# Which characters can use the vine-tangled hanging bars in LEGO Jurassic World?

Tags: lego-jurassic-world

There are a number of high-up hanging bars (actually long bones) wrapped in vines that should enable access to higher areas - however I can't seem to interact with them.

I've tried the agile characters but they don't hold on. I've had mixed luck with a 'raptor sometimes being able to access the ledge, but this seems to be a bit hit and miss?

Which characters can use these?

[image: Vine wrapped bones]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are 'raptor grapple points, but you need to target them with the secondary action (<kbd>B</kbd> on the xbox controller) to use them.

Having now played the start of part 4, I can confirm:

[image: Mr DNA Explains Raptor Rails]

[image: Targeting a rail]

Comment: I think you also have to be a way away - if I'm standing too close, the handle doesn't seem to register as a potential target...